# if else condition using sql query

Tags: sql

I have problem to generate SQL query for below table.
Here is my table:

```
County          | Store     | Stock | Display | Designation
--------------- | --------- | ----- | ------- | ------------
USA             | USD       | 1     | Yes     | Merchandiser
USA             | USD       | 2     | Yes     | Promoter
```

I want to be result like this

```
County          | Store     | Stock | Display | Designation
--------------- | --------- | ----- | ------- | ------------
USA             | USD       | 2     | Yes     | Merchandiser
USA             | USD       | 2     | Yes     | Promoter
```

The Scenario is if Designation is Promoter, use both Display and Stock data.
If Designation is from Merchandiser, use data from Promoter for Stock data
How can i achieve this?

Comment: This question does not currently meet StackOverflow rules. Please show what you've tried so far, and some more examples, some that will be changed/updated and some that will not.

Comment: USA is a country, not a county.

Comment: Perhaps a self left join? Add some more sample data and adjust the expected result, to make things clearer.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below code to create temporary table

```
--===== If the test table already exists, drop it
 IF OBJECT_ID('TestDB..#mytable','U') IS NOT NULL
     DROP TABLE #mytable
 --===== Create the test table with 
 CREATE TABLE #mytable 
        (
        Country varchar(20),
        Store varchar(20),
        Stock int,
        Display varchar(5),
        Designation varchar(20)
        )
   --===== Insert the test data into the test table
 INSERT INTO #mytable 
       (Country, Store, Stock, Display, Designation)


 SELECT 'SG','a','2','YES','Merchandiser' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'SG','a','4','YES','Promoter'
```

Now use the below above query

```
SELECT Country, 
       Store , 
       (CASE WHEN (Designation = 'Merchandiser') THEN (SELECT SUM(STOCK) FROM #mytable WHERE Country = Country AND Designation = 'Promoter' GROUP BY Country) ELSE STOCK END) AS "stock",
       Display, 
       Designation FROM #mytable
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select a.Country, a.Store
, Stock = CASE WHEN a.Designation = "Merchendiser" THEN b.Stock ELSE a.Stock
, Display = CASE WHEN a.Designation = "Merchendiser" THEN b.Display ELSE a.Display
, a.Designation
FROM YourTable a LEFT JOIN YourTable b WHERE b.Designation = "Promoter"
```

may do the trick. Unable to test at the moment.

Edit: I see that you havent stated which SQL you use (i.e. SQL server, MySQL, PostgreSQL etc., so depending on that this solution may not be able to run).

Comment: needs to account for when b is null (ie, no promoter)

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
SELECT County, 
           Store , 
           (CASE WHEN (Designation = 'Merchandiser') THEN (SELECT SUM(STOCK) FROM TABLE WHERE County = County AND Designation = 'Promoter' GROUP BY County) ELSE STOCK END) AS "stock",
           Display, 
           Designation
FROM table
```

This request give you the needed result.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are expecting query like this

```
    Select a.Country, a.Store
    , (CASE WHEN a.Designation = "Merchendiser" THEN (select  Top 1 b.Stock from YourTable b where b.Designation = "Promoter" and b.Country = a.Country and b.Store = a.Store order by id desc) ELSE a.Stock) as Stock
    , a.Display
    , a.Designation
    FROM YourTable a WHERE b.Designation = "Promoter"
```